# .Net Hosting in VB6 with mscoree.CorRuntimeHost causes "Object Required" error

Tags: .net, vb6

I need to use AIEncryptor.dll (which is a .net dll) from VB6 environment but it shows an "Object Required" error in the vb6 environment. Why is it happening. Anybody please help me on this

And I cannot use regasm.exe to register this lib ?

Here is my vb6 code

> ```
> Dim CORHost As New mscoree.CorRuntimeHost
> Dim domain As AppDomain
>
> Dim AssemblyFilename As String
> Dim Classname As String
> Dim Result As Object
> Dim objEnc As Object
>
>
> AssemblyFilename = "D:\MyProject\AIEncryptor.dll"
> Classname = "AcceleratedIdeas.AIEncryptor"
>
> CORHost.Start
> CORHost.CurrentDomain domain
>
>
> Set Result = domain.CreateInstanceFrom(AssemblyFilename, Classname).Unwrap
>   Result.InitVector = "@1B2c3D4e5F6g7H8"
> ```

You can download the AiEncryptor.dll from [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VFDf5I3ui37oqvHNRKXD0Ggs2rejUdNA/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Where are you assigning he `domain` variable?

Comment: `domain` variable is assigned in `CORHost.CurrentDomain domain` It is passe to the function `CORHost.CurrentDomain` before its used

Comment: What line causes the error? Does it compile? what does this mean `And I cannot use regasm.exe to register this lib ?` are you asking why it cannot be used? Can you use regsvr to register it

Comment: `Set Result = domain.CreateInstanceFrom(AssemblyFilename, Classname).Unwrap` this line causes the error and yeah it does compile but if run the exe it shows this error....Iam in a scenario where I cannot use regasm in client system thats what I mean and its not a question. no its .net you cannot use regsvr to register.